# Calculate each row from fieldArray Reactjs Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

How to calculate useFieldArray each row for quantity and rates using React Hook Form (Functional Component)

here's my code

```
const {
  fields: partsField,
  append: partsAppend,
  remove: partsRemove,
} = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: "partslist"
});

const watchTest = useWatch({
  control,
  name: "partswatch",
}
    
          
{
  partsField.map((
    {
      id,
      sorCode,
      quantity,
      item,
      rates,
      subtotal
    },
    index
  ) => {               
  const setSubTotal = (index, quantity, rates) => {
  const amount = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(rates);
  setValue(`partswatch[${index}].subtotal`, amount);
  console.log(quantity, rates);
};

return ( 
  <input 
    {...register(`partswatch[${index}].rates`)}
    onChange={(e) => {
      const rates = e.target.value;
      setSubTotal(index, quantity, rates);
      handleChange("rates");
    }}
  />

  <input 
    {...register(`partswatch[${index}].quantity`)}
    onChange={(e) => {
      const quantity = e.target.value;
      setSubTotal(index, quantity, rates);
      handleChange("quantity");
    }}
  />

  <Input
    type="text" 
    {...register(`partswatch[${index}].subtotal`)}
  />
)
)
}
```

when I check-in console log it has undefined under setSubTotal on change

What I'd like to expect is each row subtotal will automatically calculate quantity multiply with rates and setValue to subtotal fields in particular array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue  I should pass usefieldArray name to useWatch in order to get a particular value of each fieldarray.

```
 const {
   fields: partsField,
   append: partsAppend,
   remove: partsRemove,
 } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: "partslist" // pass to useWatch()
});

const watchTest = useWatch({
 control,
 name: "partslist",
}
```